# Scala game programming - between OOP and FP

Tags: oop, scala, functional-programming

I am trying to write a tutorial game in Scala & Processing, intending to use as much FP as possible. However, I come to a conclusion that immutable-state game objects are not profitable in such application. If an object is big, it may result in quite intensive memory consumption in case of numerous such objects being constantly updated (therefore, making copies of itself each cycle), for example, using the `copy()` func. What is the default approach to resolute this? The only thing that I come up with - is to slice the object in tiny pieces-objects so that only those who need to be updated, are updated while leaving the "big" objects same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scala game programming: advancing object position in a functional style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709437/scala-game-programming-advancing-object-position-in-a-functional-style)

Comment: yah, thanks, Peter! I have been there, it is relevant and full of info, but does not take the same angle of approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A game engine is essentialy a (discrete) event simulation. Typically, these are implemented via mutable data structures such as heap for the events, quad/oct trees for spatial queries about objects and lots of hash tables.

For each of these data structures, mutable variants are faster. Furthermore, immutable data structures produce garbage which has to be collected, so the pressure on the GC is higher, and your application ends up being slower. Where real-time is a concern, GC pauses can be harmful (e.g. it may affect the framerate in your game), and this is particularly the case on platforms with less processing power, such as Android.

As for the `copy()` method - it doesn't have to copy the entire object to create the updated version. If your object is organized hierarchically in a tree-like manner (e.g. as a hierarchy of case classes), then changing one property of the object requires rewriting only one path in this tree - you won't need to rewrite everything. Still, it will be more costly than just having a mutable version and updating in-place.

Example:

```
case class World(map: Array[Item], players: Vector[Player])

case class Player(health: Int, speed: Int, weapon: Weapon, shield: Shield)

case class Weapon(strength: Int, ammo: Int)
```

To add more ammo to the weapon, you don't have to copy the entire `World`:

```
def setAmmo(playerNum: Int, newAmmo: Int, world: World): World = {
  val p = players(playerNum)
  world.copy(players = players.updated(playerNum, p.copy(weapon = p.weapon.copy(ammo = newAmmo))))
}
```

In this example, `map`, other `players`, and the `shield` of the modified `Player` stay the same in memory and are not eagerly copied.

I would advise going for a mutable data structure to represent the state - unless you have a concurrent game engine with (for example) a single writer that simulates the game state, and a range of readers which render output, handle sound, network and so on, the benefits of immutable data structures are close to none in this use case.

Comment: The `copy()` facility looks like it turns vals in a more expensive and somewhat safer variant of vars because it lets changing vals like mutable values (vars). Does it?

Comment: The `copy()` method on case classes creates a new case class instance with the value of the fields equal to those in the original instance, except for those fields for which you explicitly write `<fieldname> = <value>`. But it does not do a deep copy - if some of the fields is a case class, that case class instance is not copied via `copy()`, only the reference to it is copied.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, don't do premature optimisations. Have you measured your code? Maybe there is some concrete bottlenecks?

Since most of the objects consist of smaller objects joined via data stuctures, I think you can get rid of this problem by using *persistent data structures* 
.

> persistent data structure is a data structure which always preserves
>   the previous version of itself when it is modified; such data
>   structures are effectively immutable, as their operations do not
>   (visibly) update the structure in-place, but instead always yield a
>   new updated structure

[Here is wonderful talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Functional-Data-Structures-in-Scala) about some of them by [Daniel Spiewak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9815/daniel-spiewak). If you want more, take a look on [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) by Chris Okasaki.

Comment: Read that presentation by Daniel spiewak it will clear your 'copy' myths up. Functional data structures are quite fast question is , fast enough for your usecase?

Comment: @AndreasScheinert Thank youall, I find these references to be highly interesting. I will try to develop the information.

Answer (score 1):

Just embrace the fact that game state is inherently mutable. Use immutable classes only for things that are conceptually values such as position, velocity etc. This might still produce a lot of garbage, but running with escape analysis turned on might help.